# Is there a way to not pass anything to a child prop method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

**Error: TypeError: _this.props.handleChange is not a function**

I have a React component that has a prop method that is used in another view component.

The problem is that my other view components need to use my Child component but it causes an error because it is required to use the prop method.

```js
class NeedsPropMethod extends Component {
 handleChange = value => {
  // receives the value
 }

 return (
  <Child toy="car" color="blue" handleChange={this.handleChange}>
 )
}

class DoesntNeedPropMethod extends Component {
 return (
  <Child toy="car" color="blue"}>
 )
}

class Child extends Component {
 return (
  this.props.toy; // "car"
  this.props.color; // "blue"
  this.props.handleChange(value) // I do not need this but it gives me the error above
 );
}
```

Comment: you are not passing it, if you don't need it remove it.

Comment: Your `Child` class above has a syntax error. What is is *really* supposed to look like?

Comment: you can add a boolean checking, if true, return the `handlechange`, else don't run it

Comment: I wish I could but the prop method is being used in my other view component so I'm trying to figure out a way to make it reusable or something like that. Will add more code into my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add propTypes to your code like this to make it become optional

```
Child.propTypes = {
  handleChange: PropTypes.func
};
```

so your handleChange will be optional

Comment: Yes. I believe this is the way to it. I'm still having error "TypeError: _this.props.handleChange is not a function" though.

Comment: Are you using propTypes any where ?

Comment: Just for the Child component

Comment: Show me the full code of your ChildComponent that have propTypes

Comment: I just have to add an if statement if the prop method exists

Comment: you need default props, `Child.defaultProp = {
  handleChange: () => {}
};
`

Answer (score 0):

From Tony Ngo's answer

```js
Child.propTypes = {
  handleChange: PropTypes.func
};
```

then you just have to check if the prop method is used

```js
if (this.props.handleChange) {
 // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: you can add deafult props and don't have to this